# Are linear transformations between infinite dimensional vector spaces always differentiable?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, continuity, linear-transformations

In class we saw that every linear transformation is differentiable (since there's always a linear approximation for them) and we also saw that a differentiable function must be continuous, so it must be true that all linear operators are continuous, however, I just read that between infinite dimensional vector spaces this is not necessarily true. I would like to know where's the flaw in my reasoning (I suspect that linear transformations between infinite dimensional vector spaces are not always differentiable).

Answer (score 1):

The differentiation *operator* is linear but not bounded in $\mathcal{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ (which is infinite dimensional over $\mathbb{R}$). Hence, it's not continuous as all continuous linear operators in Banach spaces are bounded. To see that it's not bounded, consider what differentiation does to the sequence of functions $$f_n(x) = \sqrt{n}\, e^{-n^2 x^2}$$

Also, it matters how differentiation is defined. For another example which is kind of different, consider conjugation in complex numbers where we view $\mathbb{C}$ as a $2$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Conjugation is then linear and continuous because $f(a+bi)=a-bi$ but as a map from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ it's not differentiable because it fails to satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Maybe it's important to add that *bounded* in infinite dimensional analysis means **bounded in a ball** and not bounded in the whole domain.

Comment: @NickA. I'm afraid you're wrong. Bounded here means bounded in the operator norm and by definition, $T: X \to X$ is a bounded linear operator iff $\|T(u)\| \leq M \| u \|$ for all $u \in X$ and some positive constant $M$. See Royden's Real Analysis, chapter 13, section 2. It makes sense because intuitively, It's not difficult to see that the size of a ball in a linear space doesn't matter because things can be scaled. So, there's no fixed radius really.

Comment: I don't see how what we are saying contradicts each other :). I just thought that for someone new to these areas maybe it is useful to  comment on the difference on terminology.

Comment: @NickA. I didn't say we contradicted each other. What I intended to say was that your interpretation of bounded was wrong probably because the definition works for all $u \in X$, not just some particular vectors in a specific ball. So, indeed, it's about the whole domain. Or am I mistaken or missing something?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, if a linear function is bounded on *some* closed ball (of finite radius) then it is bounded in **all balls ** (through translations and rescaling) and therefore to the ball of radius $1$, which is the usual definition (you probably have to use the triangle inequality somewhere). If you are not convinced I will provide a proof as a separate answer :).

Comment: @NickA. That's exactly what I told you to point to the fact that mentioning "a ball" isn't really necessary when we're dealing with Banach spaces and linear operators. When you say a ball, what are you referring to exactly? A ball in $X$ or a ball in $L(X)$?